# How should I fetch relational/nested data in Redux?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, asynchronous, react-redux

What is the most performant way to handle the following situation? Is there a different way to handle this (other than the options I describe) that is more efficient? Is there a 'standard' way of managing it?

Say I have the following endpoints:

```
/posts

/users
```

GET /posts:

```
[{
id: 1, 
title: 'Some post',
userId: 1,
...other post data
},
...more posts
]
```

GET /users/1:

```
[{
id: 1, 
name: 'ExampleUser',
...other user data
},
...more users
]
```

I want to return a list of posts which show some basic information about the user who created them. In order to do this. I will need to fetch the list of posts and then for each post fetch the user. One user may be referenced in multiple posts.

The React components are organized as (pseudocode):

```
<PostsList posts={posts}>
<Post post={post}>
<UserInfo user={user} />
</Post
</PostsList>
```

**Option A:** dispatch(fetchPosts()) in PostsList, then dispatch(fetchUser(post.userId) in each Post (or in each UserInfo)

Pros: Pretty easy to implement; doesn't need specialized action (ie fetchPostsWithUserInfo())

Cons: Multiple components must be connected to the store; knowing when to render a component or a loading spinner can get into complex logic; the same user can be fetched multiple times (even if fetchUser(post.userId) dispatches an action recording which users are being fetched when the action is initiated, this doesn't seem to completely prevent duplicate calls).

**Option B:** handle in actions

```
const fetchPostsWithUsers = () => dispatch => {
dispatch(fetchPostsWithUsersStart());

fetchPostsFromServer()

.then(res => {
dispatch(fetchPostsSuccess());
const users = getListOfUniqueUserIds(res.data);
users.forEach(userId => dispatch(fetchUser(userId)));
})

.catch(err => dispatch(fetchPostsError()));
}
```

Pros: No duplicate calls, fewer connected components

Cons: Still have issues with lots of loading checks; possibly missing information if some calls fail; tightly couples posts call to user data fetching

**Option C:** Like Option B, but use a Promise.all to fetch the user data and then have only one success call (dispatch(fetchPostsWithUserDataSuccess())

Pros: Fewer loading checks, all-or-nothing so no partially missing data

Cons: All-or-nothing so if once fetch fails have to re-fetch all data; slow response time because need to wait for all individual calls to complete before any data is made available

I have attempted at length to find information on this topic, but I have not been able to find any information, which surprises me because I imagine it is a common case. It might be that I am just ignorant of the correct terminology to describe the problem, in which case I would very much appreciate knowing the correct terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option A** is good choice, as you'll be able to reuse each container component separately. You just need to ***debounce*** the fetch calls so the same ones don't run multiple times simultaneously.